# Custom user registration

Tags: user-registration

I want to Implement custom user registration process in my wordpress theme. Can anyone please explain me the complete process for user registration.

**Note:**
I don't want to use default register action of wordpress. I know that we can register users through url:

> `http://site-name.com/wp-login.php?action=register`

I want to design my own user registration form. So kindly do not suggest any plugin or gravity forms or any other third party software/plugin.

Comment: This tutorial worked well for me.
https://code.tutsplus.com/series/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow--cms-816

Answer (score 2):

You can create and page and assign template to that page. Some Demo of registration url i am sending.

http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1012-wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields/

http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.